# apt-get man page weird flag

Tags: linux-mint, apt, man, options

I just looked up the man page of `apt-get` via `man apt-get` and it shows me a weird flag in the synopsis section. It's the first one. Each x is a capitalized/uncapitalized character.

```
SYNOPSIS
       apt-get [-xxxxxxx] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file]
               [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] {update | upgrade |
               dselect-upgrade | dist-upgrade |
               install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               remove pkg...  | purge pkg...  |
               source pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               build-dep pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               download pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               check | clean | autoclean | autoremove | {-v | --version} |
               {-h | --help}}
```

I'm using Linux Mint 19.2.
What could be the purpose of this flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The synopsis reads:

```
SYNOPSIS
       apt-get [-asqdyfmubV] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] {update |
               upgrade | dselect-upgrade | dist-upgrade |
               install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | remove pkg...  | purge pkg...  |
               source pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               build-dep pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
               download pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | check | clean | autoclean |
               autoremove | {-v | --version} | {-h | --help}}
```

The `-asqdyfmubV` is a set of individual single letter options that do not take option arguments (`-a`, `-s`, `-q` etc.)  These options are described later in the `apt-get` manual.

Options that do not take arguments may be bunched together in a single string.  You get this with other utilities to, for example the `rf` in `rm -rf` is the two individual options `-r` and `-f`, not a single `-rf` option.  Since neither takes an argument, they may be written together like `-rf` or `-fr`.